# How to deselect the radio button options in a ButtonGroup in Java?

Tags: java

I am having a problem with my radio buttons. It is by default getting selected each time I used to get to the next part of my project. How to deselect a selected radio button in a button group by clicking a button?

Answer (score 1):

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
...
group.clearSelection();
```

clearSelection() method will do the work.